# Can I generate a new Nether in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I don't like Hell, can I go somewhere else?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19308/i-dont-like-hell-can-i-go-somewhere-else)

My server runs 1.8 - but the 1.9 update will introduce some nice new Nether features.

So is it possible to generate a new nether without generating a new world?

Comment: Bukkit or Vanilla

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[As far as I am aware](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Alpha_Level_Format#The_Nether), the nether is just another directory in your worlds directory called `DIM-1`. From what I understand, removing that subdirectory will remove your nether and force Minecraft to generate a new one upon visiting it (using the *current* terrain generator - this means you may get different Nethers across different versions of Minecraft if the terrain generator has changed between them).

But please do make a backup :)

Make sure Minecraft isn't running in the background while trying to make the changes to your DIM-1, because it won't work.

Comment: Backups, backups, backups.