# How can I force the regeneration of the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

With the release of the Nether update on June 23, I want to re-explore the new Nether dimension in my existing world by regenerating it. How can I do this in Bedrock Edition?

The [working solution for Java Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19308) does not works on Bedrock.

Answer (score 1):

[This video](https://youtu.be/goUYU4siVU4) explains it pretty good:

1. [download mcctoolchest](http://mcctoolchest.com/Download)
2. copy your world, just to be save
3. open mcctoolchest and select the copy of your world
4. delete all nether regions